# i have this error with my own php function

Tags: php, mysql

I have this function:

```
function OUTconf($conf_name){
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT CONF_VALUE FROM ".prefix."CONFIG WHERE CONF_NAME='".$conf_name."'") or die(mysql_error());
    $rs  = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
    $val = $rs['CONF_VALUE'];
    return $val;
}
```

and I have this html form:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> <? OUTconf("SITE_TITLE"); ?> </title>
</head>
<body>
<? echo 'hello !!'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

but when i test the code i got this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare outconf() (previously declared in C:\AppServ\www\pv\includes\functions.php:13) in C:\AppServ\www\pv\includes\functions.php on line 18
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: Is this function in an included file? Did you include the flie twice without using `include_once`?

Comment: Please dont use <? instead of <?php and $sql = mysql_query??? Partying like it 1999 I see...

Comment: @nickb -- i tested it, the same problem

Comment: What is on line 13 and line 18 of functions.php respectively?

Comment: @Michael -- yes it is, yes i did but whit `require` not `include_once`

Comment: @SoNiC_H So you need to use `require_once` instead of `require`.

Comment: @deceze -- the line 13 is `function OUTconf($conf_name){` and 18 `}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare outconf() (previously declared in C:\AppServ\www\pv\includes\functions.php:13) in C:\AppServ\www\pv\includes\functions.php on line 18

This means that functions.php is trying to declare the function OUTconf() while it's already declared (by the same script).

Most probably you are including functions.php twice. Try using [`include_once`](http://php.net/include_once) instead of [`include`](http://php.net/include).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are declaring that function in multiple places which causes that error. Ensure that you are only putting the line "`function OUTconf($conf_name){` " in one place and NOT anywhere else in the code file or other files that you have included.